# How to delete everything from string up to the specific character in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I wanted to extract only date from following string. Here is variable:

```
file = '62-201809.csv'
```

I used `rsplit` to get rid of file csv extension like this:

```
splitf = file.rsplit('.', 1)[0]
```

I got `62-201809` so it's okey but now i need to get rid of everything to '-' and store only `201809` into variable.How to do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using:

```
>>> file = '62-201809.csv'
>>> file.split('-', 1)[1].split('.')[0]
'201809'
>>>
```

Or use regex:

```
>>> import re
>>> file = '62-201809.csv'
>>> re.search('-(\d+)', file).group(1)
'201809'
>>>
```

Answer (score 0):

If want only use split can do that:

```
filen = '62-201809.csv'
number = filen.split('.')[0]
number2 = number.split('-')[1]

print(number2)
```

first get only number, and later the number 201809 only.